# Compile error with operator ""&""" vhdl

Tags: vhdl, operator-keyword, comparator

I'm programming VHDL and I have a problem when compiling the testbench. Get the following error:

Error (10327): VHDL error at comparador_12_tb.vhd(56): can't determine definition of operator ""&"" -- found 0 possible definitions

**Code**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity comparador_12 is
port( num1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  
      num2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        clock : in std_logic;
      menor : out std_logic;   
      igual : out std_logic;   
      mayor : out std_logic
       );
end comparador_12;

architecture behavioral of comparador_12 is
begin
    process(num1,num2)
        begin    
            if (num1&num1&num1 > num2&num2&num2 ) then  
                menor <= '0';
                igual <= '0';
                mayor <= '1';
            elsif (num1&num1&num1 < num2&num2&num2) then    
                menor <= '1';
                igual <= '0';
                mayor <= '0';
            else    
                menor <= '0';
                igual <= '1';
                mayor <= '0';           
        end if;
    end process;   
end behavioral;
```

**Testbench**

```
LIBRARY ieee;                                               
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;                                

ENTITY comparador_12_tb IS
END comparador_12_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF comparador_12_tb IS
-- constants                                                 
-- signals                                                   
SIGNAL igual : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL mayor : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL menor : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL num1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL num2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
constant clk_period : time := 20 ns;
signal x,y : std_logic;

COMPONENT comparador_12
    PORT (
    igual : BUFFER STD_LOGIC;
    mayor : BUFFER STD_LOGIC;
    menor : BUFFER STD_LOGIC;
    num1 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    num2 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
    uut : comparador_12
    PORT MAP (
-- list connections between master ports and signals
    igual => igual,
    mayor => mayor,
    menor => menor,
    num1 => num1,
    num2 => num2
    );

clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;  
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;  
end process;

tb : process
begin
        num1 <= "1001";
        num1 <= "1100";
        num1 <= "0100";
        num2 <= "1110";
        num2 <= "1101";
        num2 <= "1000";
        x <= num1&num1&num1;
        y <= num2&num2&num2;
    wait for 10 ns;
end process;            
END behavioral;
```

Comment: The VHDL compiler can't find an overload for "&" which takes 3 4-bit inputs and makes a 1-bit output, because the result (in "X" and "Y") will be 12 bits. What do you want X and Y to be?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the following signal declarations in your test bench:

```
signal num1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
signal x,y : std_logic;
```

And the code:

```
x <= num1&num1&num1;
```

`&` is the concatenation operator. In this case, you are concatenating a 4-bit vector with itself, creating a 12-bit vector. You are then assigning the result to a single-bit `std_logic` signal. I'm not sure what you would expect to happen here, but this is the reason for the error.

Comment: Do you happen to know if will correctly perform the concatenation because '&' isn't a valid signal name character?  I wasn't sure since I would never try something like that without spaces, haha.  Also its probably worth mentioning that if he's trying to a logical and he needs to use the 'and' keyword.

Comment: @Ian I assumed that since it had identified the `&` as an operator, that this is allowed; a quick test in modelsim appears to confirm. I couldn't think of a reason to use reductive (since the target is an `std_logic`) `and` on a triple concatenation of the *same* vector, so did not guess further at the intention of this line.

Comment: yeah I came to the same conclusion, just wondering if anyone knew definitely if that was supported and why.  I supposed that is a side effect of limiting signal names to numbers, letters, and underscores.  And agreed, but I can't think of a great reason to use concatenation there either haha.

Comment: sorry guys, i'm a newbie and i use the concatenation because i have a problems and one of this is programming a 12 bit comparator using 4 bit comparator in cascade xD